# PowerShell to add user in permission group does not work always

Tags: 2013, powershell, sharepoint-on-prem

Below is my code to add the user to the permission group.

```
function SetUserIntoGroup{
    param([string]$WebUrl)
    $WebUrl
    $ADGroupName = "AD Group Name"
    $SPGroupName = "Project Owners"
    echo "Function Called"
    $site = Get-SPSite $WebUrl
    $web = $site.OpenWeb()
    $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $true

    try{

        $user = $web.EnsureUser($ADGroupName)
        $user.Name
        $user.LoginName
        if(@($web.SiteGroups.GetCollection(@($SPGroupName))).Count -eq 1){
            echo "Group Found"
            $SPGroup1 = $web.SiteGroups[$SPGroupName]
            $SPGroup1.Name
            # Check if user does not exist in group then only add to the group.
            $SPGroup1.AddUser($user)
            Write-Output "$user added to $SPGroup"
        }
    }
    catch [Exception]{
      Write-Host $_.Exception.GetType().FullName, $_.Exception.Message -foregroundcolor "magenta"
    }
    finally{
        $web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = $false

        if($web){
        echo "Disposing web"
        $web.Dispose();
        }
        if($site){
        echo "Disposing site"
        $site.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

However, it does not give me the error when I run the code. It sometimes adds the user to the permission group and sometimes does not add. I can't figure out what is the exact scenario when it does not work. If I run multiple times then I get the user added to the group.

Please help me to solve the issue. One more thing, is the code written in good approach or needs to be modified?

TIA.

Comment: It appears to not find the group in "if(@($web.SiteGroups.GetCollection(@($SPGroupName))).Count -eq 1){". Can you just omit that IF check, I think it will not throw error in case user already exists in a group so that IF might not be necessary.

Comment: Okay, I will check with suggested changes and let you know.